# Find new values after a specific date

Tags: mysql

I need a bit help to solve this problem.
I have a database that looks like this :

```
Equipement | Card | SerialNumber | Date     | other | irrelevant | columns
toto1      | aaaa | a1a1a1       | 06/06/15 | efdfd | dfdfdfdfdf | dfdfdf  
toto2      | bbbb | b2b2b2       | 06/06/15 | fdgdf | yztedg erg | raergr
toto1      | aaaa | a1a1a1       | 06/07/15 | sdfsd | zrtyeggae  | dfdfde 
toto2      | bbbb | b2b2b2       | 06/07/15 | gaery | ghffffffff | qaeryh
toto3      | cccc | c3c3c3       | 06/07/15 | gezry | eryefefetu | lgfhg
```

What i'm looking for is a query that would find new values after a specific date. For exemple I want all the new values that weren't already in base the 06/06/07.
So the query would just return `toto3;cccc;c3c3c3;06/07/15` since `toto1;aaaa;a1a1a1` and `toto2;bbbb;b2b2b2` were already in base the 06/06/15.

I solved my problem already with a bit of scripting (saving all the values from the 06/06/15 in an hash, and then comparing with the rest of the table), but I'm almost sure there is a way to do it in a "simple" SQL query.

If anyone could help me I would appreciate :)

Thanks !

Comment: This is why you normalize your database. Bad db design bites you in the butt every time.

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: It looks like an array of string - Mb you could consider using explode & normalize your database. Otherwise WE can use regex to find your need but it won't be only an Sql Query.

Comment: @ Falt4rm I'm assuming this is just a .csv export to show the data. Might be wrong....

Comment: Hope so - But regarding the needs in result query it can be :(

Comment: It's not even an export i was just giving you the basic form of my mysql table, but it is a classic mysql database and table. I "drew" it more explicitly. My bad

Comment: Well the only way I would know how to do this would be to use "GROUP BY Equipment". I'd read up a bit on aggregate sql statements.

The logic behind this would be to separate your data into chunks based on the Equipment number and then do some logic to get Dates only after "x".

Unfortunately I don't have mySQL on this machine and know I'll butcher the syntax if try to write it with no IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SerialNumber seems to be a "primary key". We can use `NOT IN` clause.

SqlFiddle : [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1ad8/1)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE SerialNumber NOT IN (SELECT SerialNumber
                       FROM Table1
                       WHERE Date <= 'The Date requested')
```

Comment: This ! I need to learn those sub queries they are really effective :)
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Explanation : I gathered all the SerialNumbers present Before 'the Date requested' (those we don't want) and remove from the full table. It remains the row with SerialNumber that didn't exist before 'the date requested'.